# Hisense Sero 7 - USB Debugging Enabled But Not Working

Tags: android, debugging, adb, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I recently received a Hisense Sero 7 Pro Edition (running android 4.2) for use with development. I am currently on my Linux box trying to get it setup to be used over here since I seem to have better luck with the NDK on this computer.

Aside the point, I have the vendor ID registered in adb_usb.ini and its not seeming to want to  play nice with my computer. When I plug the device in it says USB debugging is enabled as well as its connected as a media device. I have heard a few places that connecting as a media device causes some issues with USB debugging. Maybe that is the issue, if so how do I turn that off?

Kinda at a loss here. How do I go about getting this working?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I have the same Hisense Sero 7 tablet. The id is 109b, which can be found [here in the list of USB Vendor IDs](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). This must be done in **addition** to the [answer explained by Sumit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238925/40961).

In addition to editing 51-android.rules, you will also need to add third party vendor Id to `adb_usb.ini`

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.

0x109b
```

then in the terminal:

```
adb kill-server

adb devices

> List of devices attached 
> 015d8bed094ffe06   device
```

P.S: this is the command I used
gedit `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

Comment: Ahhh I will try this ASAP... I'm sorry I got tied up a good bit of things!

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I have a method which can help u. Just follow the steps...

1. Type ***lsusb*** in your terminal after plugging in your device to your system. You will see some codes. Now remove the device and again run command. Now you will notice that one of the code is missing.
   Note down the missing code because that is the code of your device manufacturer.
2. This is the code in my case (0bb4)

Bus 002 Device 014: ID ***0bb4***:0ce6 High Tech Computer Corp.

3.Now go to this path ***/etc/udev/rules.d***

4.You will notice a file  named ***51-android.rules.***

5.Open it and copy and paste the last line but change. The last line looks like the one i pasted above. Now in the copied line replace the code with your device code (0bb4 in my case).

1. Now type ***adb kill-server***
2. Now type ***adb devices*** and you can see your device listed.

Hope this will help you and ya be careful with permissions your require anywhere.

Comment: Alright apparently there is no 51-android.rules on my file system... Should I just make it? Also what exactly am I pasting in so I am not fumbling around with it?

Comment: yes, you have to make it then I am here pasting text from my 51-android.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"

This idVendor is the thing i am talking about which you have to note down by running command lsusb

Answer (score -1):

Goto setting/about/build tap build 8 times. Bazinga developer options open up when you back out